# Are Tony's glasses made up of nano particles?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the beginning of *Avengers: Infinity War* Tony Stark's glasses suddenly vanished.

Were they made of nano particles which dissolved and became part of his suit?

[image: Iron Man suiting up while removing glasses]

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson we must prevent posts causing spoilers, right? Why did you change it to `Tony's glasses`?

Comment: Why would "Tony's glasses" be a spoiler?  The glasses or the nano-suit are not a major plot point.  The movie has been out for a number of weeks - very obsessive fans who might view small detail like this as a minor spoiler would have seen the movie.

Comment: @paul the existence and possible composition of Tony's glasses is not a spoiler.

Comment: @paul And...glasses being possibly made from nano particles is...a spoiler? Or...that Tony is in *Infinity War*?

Comment: Me thinking that it could be a spoiler is a reason of downvote? or this is already answered or this is poorly written or this opinion based or this is out context of movies.stackexchange. **What is the reason of downvote?**

Comment: @iandotkelly for a fan who hasnt seen the movie, we have spoiled it, that a nano suit will be used by Tony and it is so advanced that it can become Tony's specs also. It is a fantasy not a plot for everyone. Most will go to theaters just to see their favorite hero in action nothing more. They dont want to use their brains in speculating what would happen next. So we have spoiled. I suppose!!

Comment: Its not for me paul to answer for the downvoter, but I suspect its not for the 'spoiler'.  I believe its much more likely that people think its a relatively minor detail which therefore makes the question less interesting to some.  Also, if you view the movie you can literally see the glasses disappear in his hands at the same moment as the suit appears on him.  To the level that we can "explain" fictional supertech, it seems obvious that the glasses are made/unmade by the same or similar tech to the suit.

Comment: In my opinion, the title is not a spoiler.  The benefit of the question having a clearer title outweighs the very very minor detail it reveals.

Comment: It's a bit silly either way, that's what's causing the confusion.
His glasses could very well be particles, but why would he use his hand to remove them then? That action seems to be a bit pointless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Apparently, yes.

If you pay close attention to the scene the glasses are in Stark's hand as he pulls them from his face and as his arm lowers *the glasses disappear*.

They are not dropped or put away so we must assume that they are also nano-particle based and are subsumed into his suit.

It's difficult to show this as it's a **very** quick shot with barely a split-second between the two images but...

Glasses in hand:

[image: suited up Iron Man holding glasses]

Glasses gone:

[image: almost the same as above, but no glasses]

Comment: Phew ...finally. Else team of outliers have almost invaded the place.

Answer (score 0):

**Stark's glasses didn't vanish. He put them away.**

In the opening scene we see that he tightens up his regular clothes which will act as intermediate layer between his armour and skin later on. Then he starts walking towards Maw. In that moment, we can see Stark remove his glasses while the nano suit is still covering him. Before the suit coverage is complete, we can see Stark put away the glasses that he removed from his face moments ago.

There was no any other indication about the materials that glasses were made of, their primary goal is to comunicate with Friday and act as a HUD when needed.

I couldn't find a better quality source on YouTube at the moment, this clip is not a good quality one, apologies for that.

Answer (score -2):

Tony’s glasses were not made of nanotech but as seen in *Avengers: Endgame* when fighting Thanos, his suit

> absorbed the Stones into his hand like a gauntlet.

Basically the nanotechnology is able to grab things or in this case absorb anything that is metal and convert it into nanotechnology temporarily.

Comment: Mmmmh... I was under the impression the tech wrapped itself around the Stones, not absorbed it?

Comment: Well yes which I should’ve made more clear but it can grab or wrap itself around things that aren’t made of metal.

Comment: Only because the Gauntlet made by Stark is also nanotech right ?